# How to call a Stencil in swift with different variable name?

Tags: swift, swift-stencil

I have 2 stencil templates, which pretty much the same except the variable name is different:

template #1

```
{% for p in anArray %}
  {% if p.property1 = "abc" %}
    // some logic
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

template #2

```
{% for a in aDifferentNameArray %}
  {% if a.property1 = "abc" %}
    // same logic as template 1
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I think it will be cleaner if I can refactor this into a template and have template #1 and #2 call this new template

```
  {% if ??.property1 = "abc" %}
    // same logic as template 1
  {% endif %}
```

But problem is in template #1, the variable is `p` where as in template #2, the variable is `a`.
So what can i do to call the new template with template #1 & #2 with different variable name?

Comment: Comments in stencil are marked with `{# ... #}`, not `//`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly the use case for the [`include`](https://stencil.fuller.li/en/latest/builtins.html#include) tag. Using this tag, you can include the contents of another template, and also pass it a context of your choice.

Move `some logic` to a separate template. Let's call that file `some logic.stencil`. In there, wherever you have used `p.propertyX`, you should change it to just `propertyX`, since you are giving it `p`/`a` as the context.

some logic.stencil:

```
{% if property1 = "abc" %}
    {# same logic as template 1, except all the "p." are deleted. #}
{% endif %}
```

In template #1, do:

```
{% for p in anArray %}
    {% include "some logic.stencil" p %} {# passing "p" as the context #}
{% endfor %}
```

In template #2, do:

```
{% for a in aDifferentNameArray %}
    {% include "some logic.stencil" a %} {# passing "a" as the context #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i tried your solution above. But it does not work for me, it seems it can't resolve 'property1' in some logic.stencil despite I passed in 'p' as context.